# How to get rid of \def

Tags: macros, renewcommand, def

I was recently required by a journal to getting rid of `\def` in the definitions of my personal macros. It turns out to be not-so-easy and the naive replacement of `\def` by `\newcommand` does not always work. Is there a standard way of doing that?

Let me give two examples:

(1) `\def\res{\texttt{Res}\left(#1\right)}`
I cannot replace def by newcommand

(2) `\def\io{\infty}`
I can replace def by newcommand

Comment: I think your question will be improved if you show one or a few of the ones you have difficulties with.

Comment: You can insert `\expandafter\let \expandafter\getridofdef \csname def\endcsname` and replace all occurrences of `\def` by `\getridofdef`. Now, Your document includes no `\def` at all.

Comment: @wipet Apart from not being quite true (since `\csname def \endcsname` is still an instance of `\def`) it really is not in the spirit of the request.

Comment: If `\newcommand` doesn;t work, `\renewcommand` should.  Better uet, use another name for the macro, one that isn't alreacy being used.  If you intend to change an existing definition, **don't do it!**

Comment: @mickep thx, I gave two examples.

Comment: For your first example, which you say can't be replaced by `\newcommand`, what error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: your first example is wrong anyway (if it is a standalone definition.). Apart from this: are you sure the journal will accept \newcommand instead?

Comment: If the document is modified by my comment above, there is no `\def`. I wanted to point out that the rule "no \def in the document" is absurd. Journal needs a skilled editor who know TeX well. No to give absurd rules. The example about `\def\c` is somewhat historical. Now, we have Unicode TeX engines, so Turkish coauthor should  write “Ş” directly. If not then the editor will correct it or ask the author not to use such historical macros. LaTeX needs to free itself from the burden of history.

Answer (score 9):

In a submission there should be ***no*** `\def`, because the copy editors are afraid tha a user does things such as

```
\def\c{\gamma}
```

so making it impossible to typeset a paper by a Turkish coauthor whose name contained “Ş”. It really happened.

You may possibly use a few `\renewcommand` instructions, but mark them clearly. I'm thinking to something quite safe like

```
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}
```

but you should be ***certain*** not to modify important commands.

Your definition of `\res` is wrong anyway, because you're using a parameter in the replacement text without announcing it. Possibly

```
\newcommand{\res}[1]{\operatorname{\mathtt{Res}}(#1)}
```

I discourage you from

```
\newcommand{\io}{\infty}
```

because the standard command is semantic, yours isn't and the gain is really not worth the pain of remembering another command.

In any case, if using `\newcommand` returns an error about the command being already defined, avoid switching to `\renewcommand` unless you ***precisely*** know what you're doing (like in the `\epsilon` case, but ***not*** in the `\c` case).

Comment: Very good explanation. Sometimes what we "can" do is not what we "should" do.

Comment: I vaguely recall someone asking a question saying that they tried `\newcommand\box`, then after seeing the error message they did `\renewcommand\box` and wondered why everything was running havoc `:-)`

Comment: @campa Redefining `\box` or `\fi` are two of my favorite examples when teaching LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks, that’s very helpful.